# Appium doesn't update it's view in list element and subelements

Tags: ios, ui-automation, appium

I am working on iOS native app and when trying to read from tableView/tableCells I have a problem getting the updated values. At the first time i enter the page/screen I can see all cells. But , if i create an action that adds another cell to the table view when I try to get the list of cells I see an empty list. 
Also, When i change a subelement in that cell I can't see the changed sub element both in inspector and in the code.
I tried switching to a different page and also changing tabs in that page and reread the table/cell and subelements but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before. There is no actual reload elements kind of function that I've seen. However a workaround I've found that works is to simply find an element that exists and it'll reload the elements after it does that.

For example:

```
yourMethodThatLoadsNewElements();
driver.findElementBy(pathToElementThatExistedBefore);
driver.findElementBy(pathToElementThatWasJustLoaded);
```